# How to tighten screw in looser masonry hole?

Tags: masonry, fastener

I'm using 5/16" masonry rated screws to secure my door frame in masonry. When I use 3/16" drill bit, the screw won't go in and when I use the next size up, 1/4", the screw goes in but it doesn't lock when it reaches the end, instead spins endlessly, which indicates that there isn't enough grip for a secure torque as the hole is a little too big.

Is there something, like a non mechanical thread locker or a 2-part epoxy, that I can maybe inject into the hole (or smear around the bolt, the the former seems more realistic) that will lock it tight?

Answer (score 2):

Shop for 'masonry screw anchor' and 'machine screw anchor'. These are much more tolerant of slight dimensional inaccuracies. They come in a variety of styles designed for different applications.

I used the lead-cylinder type when framing my finished basement and they hold a heavy door frame without shaking.

I would not use epoxy or mortar because you have to hold the installation in place until the adhesive sets. Plus you can't ever remove the screws.

I'm not sure but it looks like driving special screws directly into masonry should only be done with a matching drill and driver supplied by the screw vendor.

Answer (score 0):

After several uses of drilling into concrete bits can become bent and misaligned. When this occurs the bit will actually spin in a eccentric pattern (it doesn't spin true). So you end up with a slightly wider opening. Tap-cons are very temperamental in that they won't grab if the opening is slightly larger.

This drill bit warp is common for longer bits (4" and up), but pushing with too much force, drilling in "hammer" mode and over heating will have the same effect.

1/4 inch Tap-Cons screws require a 3/16 inch bit. The smaller Tap-Cons need a 5/32 inch bit. Whatever length screw you are using calculate the minimum hole depth and add 1/8 inch. This will account for concrete dust or wood compression from the screw head.

Wall anchors can be substituted for a too large Tap-Con hole. And there is an anchoring epoxy that is used for this exact purpose sold in any contractors store.